# How get visibility of a webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

how can I check the visibility of a webview? There is no option like

```
webview.visiblity == View.Gone;
```

or

```
webview.getVisibility
```

or sth similar...

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can check like this

```
    if (webView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        //Visible
    }else if (webView.getVisibility()==View.GONE) {
        //Gone
    }else {
        //invisible
    }
```

check for more http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getVisibility%28%29

Comment: oh :/ I overlooked it apparently :) Thank you